# Trouble using/understanding JASidePanels control

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a Facebook-like menu in my application, and I found [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels).

Followed the instructions on the GitHub page and it works well, as expected. What I can't understand is how the CenterViewController is going to change when the user taps on a cell of the LeftViewController (assuming, of course, that LeftViewController has a UITableView in it).

Can anyone explain how this happens?

Answer (score 1):

The change happens here:

```
- (void)_changeCenterPanelTapped:(id)sender {
    self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[JACenterViewController alloc] init]];
}
```

So in your `UITableViewDelegate`, when the:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

is called, you need to handle it with this:

```
 self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = ...;
```

Comment: I'm asuming '...' should be the ViewController that I want to display?